# Google SpreadSheets Api blocks table after some requests

Tags: google-sheets-api

My application sends requests to Google Spreadsheets Api to write values to table.

I can successfully send only 3-4 requests after this table blocks for 6-12 hours and servers sends 503 error (unavailable). I thought that this occurs with basic filter or hyperlinks in data, but without them it doesn't work too.

Also I have another service which sends more request and updates >10 tables without errors.

My question is: May Google block requests to some table cause some specific data or some specific request?

Comment: 503 just means that service is temporarily unavailable. If you resend them after some time to they start to work? There's not much SO users can advise on with 5XX errors as they're internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was turned off spreadSheet service on dashboard of google console. Very stupid problem(
[image]